# Sync shared folder in Onedrive to external/guest Azure users

Tags: windows, sync, onedrive, file-sharing, azure

I'm looking for a way to synchronise a shared folder on OneDrive to a guest user in our company on Azure.

Basically, we created an external guest user in Azure and then shared a OneDrive folder to him. The objective would be for him to be able to sync this shared folder with his local OneDrive, make changes to it and have those changes transferred to the OneDrive cloud.

We did a test, and the user received the link to access the shared folder, but it doesn't appear in his OneDrive files on the web version, and he can only download them, as if it was a simple repository.

How can I share a folder with other people so that they can modify it?

Thank you for your answers.

[Picture of the shared folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Svaq.png)

Comment: Does he also use OneDrive for Business? Does he have the OneDrive for Business tool installed? I wouldn't recommend letting it sync to his personal OneDrive because then you don't have any control over the data and might have security or Governance issue.

Comment: See here for some additional information https://www.clouddirect.net/knowledge-base/KB0011378/syncing-your-onedrive-for-business-files